# websites blocking through Content Blocking in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, swift-extensions, safari-content-blocker

I am creating an app where I want to block few websites by using `Content Blocking Extension` in Swift.

If you guys have any idea to block websites through an app please suggest something.

Comment: I think this link may help you  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/safari-content-blocking-ios9

Comment: @remyr3my, 
If I wanted to visit the only two websites for example- www.facebook.com, www.google.com
and rest all websites should block, not only in safari but all web browsers.
How to achieve this and make the restriction on the website URL so that user can see only a few mentioned websites.

Reference App:- “OurPact” and “Freedom” apps working on.